# Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin not working on bootstrap carousel 3

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I added this [imagemap-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/imagemap-resizer) plugin to **bootstrap carousel 3** the problem i got is the plugin working only on the active image on the slider so when i swipe to another image the whole image/map coords is not working !!
how can i get it working in the whole images on the slider continent the active one and the others or even make it load on each swip ??

Comment: Could you show some code that you have tried, or maybe even a jsFiddle

Comment: i used this http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/ as slider and then add this plugin i told above i change the slider photos to local photos and added area tag on it nothing else !!

Comment: so make a jsFiddle for us demonstrating your problem so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a  for each image or create a transparent overlay image over the top of you image slider. I would go with the first option.