# Responsive Image Maps Plugin not working on bootstrap carousel 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

i solved this problem [Image Maps jQuery Plugin not working on bootstrap carousel 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488685/responsive-image-maps-jquery-plugin-not-working-on-bootstrap-carousel-3?noredirect=1#comment34212461_22488685)() by put the plugin function to load on each slide so the plugin works on the whole images but when i swipe to image which i called before the plugin stop working ..

So i want to ask the script if the active image had load the plugin function before or not if true refresh the page else load the plugin function .. Or how to know which image had been swiped before or not !!

Answer (score 1):

You should see the events section of the carousel in the docs - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

You can capture the event `slide.bs.carousel` and use it to  call the function to render images.

A code similar to this will work

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#object-images').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
         $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
    }); 
});
```